# Как создать несколько функций в цикле?

Tags: python

Задача такая, я хочу создать несколько функций, причём нужно делать это в цикле.

```
li = ['f', 'g', 'a']
res = []

for el in li:
    def a():
        return el


    res.append(a)


for func in res:
    print(func())
```

Вывод при этом будет три `'a'`, а нужно чтобы было `'f', 'g', 'a'`. Возможно ли это вообще сделать на питоне?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Внутри функции el - это глобальная переменная, при вызове функции возвращается актуальное значение этой переменной (то что в ней осталось после завершения цикла).

Тут можно использовать функцию, создающую новую функцию, передавать значение через параметр, тогда внутренняя функция будет видеть этот локальный параметр, а не глобальную переменную:

```
li = ['f', 'g', 'a']
res = []


def create_function(param):
    def a():
        return param
    return a


for el in li:
    res.append(create_function(el))


for func in res:
    print(func())
```

Comment: Ваше решение чище. В моём можно указать параметр у функции, т.е. это не совсем та функция, которая была раньше )

Comment: огромное спасибо вам всем, весь день мучился, а решение оказалось таким простым

Answer (score 2):

У вас проблема с **замыканием переменных**. Ваша функция возвращает **ссылку на переменную цикла**, а не на значение этой переменной. Решить эту проблему можно, например, зафиксировав аргумент анонимной функции, захватив таким образом значение переменной:

```py
for el in li:
    res.append(lambda el=el: el)
```

Другой вариант захватить значение переменной - через дефолтный параметр функции (по сути это тоже самое, что выше сделано через `lambda`):

```py
for el in li:
    def a(el=el):
        return el
    res.append(a)
```

Вывод в обоих случаях будет одинаковый:

```
f
g
a
```

Comment: `el=el` - это, конечно, хак. Кроме того у функции появляется параметр, которого там быть не должно. Я считаю что нужно стиснуть зубы и написать функцию, возвращающую лямбду: `def make_f(el): return lambda: el`